# Change the way log in and sign up buttons (in header) appear in mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, header

This is how the log in and sign up buttons appear in mobile (when I am logged out):

[image]

I noticed this change today. It was looking fine yesterday.

The buttons look ugly. Please fix them.

This is how they previously looked like:

[image]

---

**Update**:

This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

IMO, the buttons need a bit of distance like how they had back then. They look clumsy on [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uoGv.png) as well.

Comment: Related: [The top bar's Stack Exchange logo is permanently max-width and squeezes out the site switcher on mobile, requiring scrolling to access](/q/377585/289905).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, as you note in [your latest screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqOut.png). The new spacing issue you point out in that screenshot [has also been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417306/log-in-sign-up-buttons-very-close).