# What is the idea behind the new top header icon color?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, header

###### Before

[image]

##### After

[image]

---

If this was intended, what's the idea behind this?

More 'readable'?

---

The change seems to be platform wide, but due to the white background color on SO it does not seem to have any useful addition.

[image]

---

**Edit**
After receiving an upvote, there seems to be more change to the styling:
The blur effect seems to be new

[image]
[image]

Comment: Was just about to post this too. I'll bin mine. You've got it. On black background headers it sent from grey to white. See also [Change the way log in and sign up buttons (in header) appear in mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377567/change-the-way-log-in-and-sign-up-buttons-in-header-appear-in-mobile)

Comment: I find the reputation change indicator much harder to read now...

Comment: I find it too prominent. It was already too distracting when it was just the smaller red dot.

Comment: @AndrewMorton maybe we'll get fewer questions about how to log out now the top right buttons are so in your face. Every cloud...

Comment: This change is total eye sore. Both in dark and light headers.

Comment: Note that a bit of whitespace between the pfp and the badges/rep has been removed - [Why is the header bar suddenly brighter and with a different layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377571/why-is-the-header-bar-suddenly-brighter-and-with-a-different-layout)

Comment: Just came here looking for discussion on this - I hate it, to my eyes it makes it look blurry and less-crisp, did several double-takes. Sometimes just because you could doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I think the number in the counter seems smaller and is harder to look at.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted a feature-request about the fuzzy numbers: [Option to remove fuzzy outline and restore clarity to the counts on new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377577/option-to-remove-the-fuzzy-outline-on-the-new-header-bar) (I wonder if it should be an "answer" here?)

Comment: @for-the-love-of-soupless it's most definitely barely legible on my screens.

Comment: Reference to Stacks Design: [Activity indicator](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/activity-indicator/)

Comment: To add some information, I am referring to the inbox notifications. The header is dark, and the blur effect blends with the dark background causing the counter to look smaller.

Comment: @for-the-love-of-soupless - And bizarrely, the width of the solid background of a single-digit notification differs between light and dark. That's visible in the images above, and I can confirm it's true when it's the same digit (rather than 1 vs. 2).

Comment: @for-the-love-of-soupless it's not the blur effect that *makes it look* smaller. The entire thing is smaller. The background for the number has been shrunken down as well as the number itself. The blur takes up *some* of the old space.

Comment: @VLAZ - Oh wow, the number itself was actually made smaller? I thought it was "just" that the background it was on was smaller and the fuzziness slammed right up on it.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile I can get used to design changes. I can't get used to SE making those changes out of the sleeve, without planning, without research, without telling or consulting with anyone. Totally disappointing and annoying, every time. As for this specfic change, it's horrible, it just doesn't fit anything.

Comment: …and you can't even scroll it out of the way any more :\

Comment: On MSO: [New reputation badge looks unfinished](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416927/4642212).

Comment: Note that this has already been introduced here: [What does the blue dot in front of the review queues mean?](/q/369177/289905), [New responsive Activity page](/a/372611/289905). This is part of the Stacks design. It’s obvious that Stack Exchange wants to push the Stacks design everywhere. There’s a [design page](//stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks) and a [GitHub repo](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks). If you don’t like it, you can provide _proactive_ feedback there!

Comment: I _don't_ have eye problems, and this new blur effect makes me think for a moment that there's something in my eye. It's like the effect I get when looking at UV light in a dark room.

Comment: I wish SO devs/POs would **ask the community** for their opinion **before** doing any work much less rolling out a change that the community doesn't like, instead of cooking up an idea in the vacuum of the ivory tower and launching it from orbit.

Comment: @Bohemian or at least roll it out *and allow users to opt in to test it*.

Comment: Problem could be solved so easily by merely removing the border-radius on the numbers, allowing for more perceived space around them. It's the "pill" shape that's *killing* readability.

Comment: @Scott the actual area where the number is located is still going to be smaller, though. The shadow is the lesser problem - the bigger one is that the space for the number is not enough to provide good contrast. The shadow thing just makes it worse, since it also makes it look "busy" in a bad way.

Comment: I don't disagree @VLAZ That unnecessarily large outer ring is pretty horrible. But really reduce that border radius back to 2-4px where it used to be and a good 60%-70% of the readability issue is resolved. There will be more *perceived* space around the numbers.

Comment: @Scott border radius used to be 5px. With no shadow. But the size of the balloon was also bigger: https://i.imgur.com/V2nozTJ.png

Comment: Yeah they had to steal space from somewhere for that massive fake glow effect. (which actually, on its own, irrespective of the numbers, looks pretty bad in my opinion. It's not a "glow" nor a "shadow". Honestly, it *looks* to me more like an error than anything else - first year design student learning CSS and **over-styling** things.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Same. I myself have used uBlock origin's picker to get rid of it.

Comment: The "blur" effect is horrible. can't believe they found another way to butcher the poor header

Comment: On the dark background the "glow" is negligible and doesn't *nothing* but impede readability. The red is practically invisible except where it crosses over the icons. And the green just looks like something is "wrong".

Comment: Looks like this is fixed now?  Although in an uncanny bit of timing, Stack Overflow is now in "April Fools" mode, so if you miss those stark white icons, go check out the "Hot Dog Stand" theme.

Comment: @mwfearnley - Yeah, love the timing. :-) Now if they'd just [fix the other thing they changed at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377577/option-to-remove-the-fuzzy-outline-on-the-new-header-bar)...

Answer (score 59):

Depending on the actual network, a solid fraction of your user base is already old, and we will (hopefully) get older over the next years.

Leading to: eyesight might be more and more an issue for some of your users. So reducing the contrast area isn't a good choice, at least for some of your users.

The old notification hit a sweet spot for me, and I immediately noticed the change (dark theme) and disliked it. Where my main complaint is with the reputation count, because that is a **number** that I want to read. If we would solely be talking about a binary notification (it is there / it is not there), then it might be okay. But encoding more *information* like that, I just don't like it.

(maybe because the actual number almost overlaps with the achievements trophy icon: white number too close to the white icon)

Comment: I just wish they really gave it so much thought. I'm afraid the truth is most likely much more simple: someone thought "let's make it different to justify my salary", and that's the result. Doubt there's any planning here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I disagree with that pretty negative view on front end changes. Yeah, maybe the responsible people didn't fully think it through, or didn't consider it worth alpha/beta testing. But to claim "they just did that to produce *something*", that is call I won't support. I know enough designers and front end developers who put a lot of discipline and diligence in their work ... thus not engaging in such cliches.

Comment: Note: the user base likely gets new young users as time goes by... At least I hope for SE that it's not only we, the same old people who registered some 5/10 years ago, who use their sites.

Comment: @dim Sure. I am perfectly fine with UIs adapting to stay relevant with younger people. It is all about balancing: keep things fancy and attractive for everybody, but ensure they really work on "function level" for all (major) user groups.

Comment: I think that "let's make it different to justify my salary" is the reason behind a lot of changes in software UI across entire industry.

Comment: @wha7ever Maybe, but then it is also a cliche that doesn't contribute much insightful information.

Answer (score 14):

For anybody who wants it, I (Ginger) made a userscript to revert the header to its original format: https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/raw/main/SE%20Header%20Fix.user.js

If there's anything I missed, feel free to tell me!

Comment: Anybody who downloaded this prior to this comment needs to reinstall as old versions break voting icons and a few other things

Comment: The review queue icon looks squarish rather than round with this userscript installed, on my FF 98. Otherwise - definitely an improvement, although not all the way to how it was before. Thanks :-)

Comment: @einpoklum I'll look into it.

Comment: Also, if you could add more padding around the numbers within the bubbles, that would also be awesome.

Comment: @einpoklum Okay, I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Well... not the top&bottom padding for the reputation change, still.

Comment: *I'm not thrilled with the fuzzy border* ... that was just a dry run for the 3D filter coming today ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not thrilled with the fuzzy border either, but instead of a user script, I wanted to just make a style change.

It can be used with the [stylus extension](https://add0n.com/stylus.html)

It's partly inspired by the post on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/9367/se-header-fix-userscript) by [Ginger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1116284/ginger)

Before:
[image]

After:
[image: After]

```css
/* Remove the shadows and make the blobs larger */

.s-navigation--item .s-activity-indicator,
.js-inbox-button .s-activity-indicator,
.js-achievements-button .s-activity-indicator {
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 17px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.s-topbar .s-topbar--content .s-topbar--item.js-inbox-button .s-activity-indicator {
    right: 25%;
}

#review-button .s-activity-indicator {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: This works well. There are also fuzzy blue notification icons in the user profile on the left side of the activity tab (bounties, responses, etc.) It would be great if those could be defuzzified.

Comment: @ColleenV Done. I made them all 1 pixel higher, since the values seemed to not be centered.

Comment: [Reputation indicator with *rounded* sides and *no* fuzziness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAiIW.png)

Comment: @Justin Too round for me, but you can play with the `border-radius` to get your desired roundness. Stylus will update the page on-the-fly :)

Comment: @Unconsidered: I was thinking that's how it would possibly look if SE took out the fuzziness and left the indicator *rounded* instead of rectangular. Although... I would like things to get back to normal, or at least the way *you've* done it :-)

Comment: Nice work (though I don't care for the centering this applies, personally)

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

The white icons have been toned down a bit (it's much better now).

From Scott's post in [Can I dim the top bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377607/can-i-dim-the-top-bar) (gif):

[image: gif]

---

**UPDATE #2**

Looks like they removed the fuzzy outline:

[image]

Comment: But it's still small and annoying :-(

Answer (score 6):

I added a few answers on other posts that I feel address the main points here, so I'm going to summarize and link those instead of copy/pasting.

[Regarding icon/text color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377658/395497) tl;dr Color was chosen for design consistency along with some contrast improvements. We dimmed the icon/font color on network dark version a bit because it felt really bright.

[Regarding notification indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377749/395497) tl;dr We updated the indicators to remove the transparent shadow because it made the indicator count as well as the icon below a bit hard to read/visually absorb

Comment: Both fixes are improvement, but the text is still hard to read on notification indicator because background area is to small.

Answer (score 5):

I liked the previous smoother contrast of the icon colors against the background better. For me the effect is that this new **increased contrast is more noticeable in the corner of my eye so I'm drawn to look at the top bar icons more** even when there's no notification.

Answer (score -46):

**I like it**. There's greater contrast than before.

[image] and  [image]

Today  30/03/2022
[image] and  [image]

**UPDATE** 31/03/022
[image] and [image]

The contrast level has been slightly decreased since yesterday. I still like the recent change but I would far prefer the top bar to be non-sticky and to be less jet-black it has always looked so horrible on the EL&U site.

In [2018 I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315895/three-hamburgers-but-still-no-direct-link-to-meta)

> Now, I'm not a designer but it seems to me that the sandwich menu should be brighter. Currently it is practically invisible, a dark grey icon on a pitch black background, it doesn't light up and it's situated on the far right-hand side.

ORIGINAL

> The change seems to be platform wide, but due to the white background color on SO it does not seem to have any useful addition.

However, on the black top bar which is network-wide the new brighter icons  will help users and visitors alike with eyesight problems.

But can we have the option to unstick the [top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar) please? That way any users who feel *blinded* by the bright icons can scroll down the page and not feel annoyed.

Comment: This doesn't help *anyone* with eye problems... Probably the icons, but not the indicators (which IMO is more important).

Comment: **No**, there's less contast for the notification badges, by **any** definition of the word contrast. The only help it offers to users with eyesight problems is to exacerbate those problems.

Comment: @Stu If a somewhat grey icon is now whiter doesn't that mean an increase in contrast?

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Yes there's multiple styles here, I should clarify I'm referring to the notification badges - this is the change that really annoys.

Comment: Isn't this what the "high contrast" theme (in beta testing) is for? And not something that everybody needs?

Comment: @samcarter_I don't know what you mean by beta testing. Do you mean that the company should have told the community before rolling out the change?  Wasn't there a recent post about people with impaired eyesight and how SE should adress this issue. Let me see if I can find it somewhere

Comment: Found it, finally [Is Stack Exchange accessible for the blind and visually impaired and what can be done to improve it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358372/is-stack-exchange-accessible-for-the-blind-and-visually-impaired-and-what-can-be#:~:text=https%3A//meta.stackexchange.com/a/376822/223820)

Comment: Too much contrast is as bad as not enough contrast. I was fine with the old design (except for the green notification color that was too light) so it made reading numbers difficult. But, current design is way worse. Now I cannot even directly look at header icon area (especially black header + white icons) without straining my eyes, and I still cannot read the numbers.

Comment: If there are users that really need extreme high contrast theme, then there should be separate themes to cater for their needs (think of Windows high contrast themes).

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Stackoverflow already has a separate high contrast theme, it can be activated in the profile. They'd just have to bring it to the rest of the network.

Comment: I actually like it either, not sure why it's absolutely hated

Comment: It’s the green notification icons that are the problem, not the bright white icons in the bar. The red notification icons don’t show the issue as much because you can’t really see the “glow’ on them. They’re just smaller. the text in the green icons isn’t even aligned properly and looks really crowded. I didn’t downvote, but I think you missed the point.

Comment: Then make everything contrast to solving all eye-sight issues at once! It is over-highlighted that catch my view there and that hurts my eyes!

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile there is a high contrast theme. It does not really help after this change. [The notification is tiny](https://i.imgur.com/g2RCR2I.png)

Comment: @ColleenV I thought I had suggested an explanation for the question in the title **Idea behind new top header icon color**, OK I also read comments elsewhere that talk about the halo but I wasn't and I'm not bothered by that. Yes, the earned rep number could be sharper, could be slightly larger, but generally speaking the high contrast works. The hamburger icons seemed hidden before, as if they were of secondary importance. Perhaps newcomers on the mainsites will now be enticed to click on these menus and discover that there is a place called meta?

Comment: There's no reason why the high contrast white icons have to be accompanied by smaller, poorly rendered notification icons.  What is the point of removing a quarter of the area of the notification to add a fuzzy outline that does nothing to improve readability? All it does is reduce the amount of space for symbols in the solid area of the notification. I still think that you aren't really understanding the problem from the original question. It's talking specifically about the red and green notifications, not the white static symbols on the bar.