# Header hiding top of page on Firefox

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, meta

With the latest layout (rev 2022.3.30.41810), the top of the main content goes under the header:

[image: Top of page missing]

As you can see, the page is scrolled all the way to the top.

The problem exists in Firefox 98.0.2 on Windows 10 for the sites stackoverflow.com, meta.stackexchange.com, and electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do you have the [non-sticky user script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368984/237989) installed? I had to disable it because today's redesign broke this useful script :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is caused by 3rd party tools, not SE software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Today's unannounced(!) changes to the design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377568/237989) unfortunately broke a couple of essential user scripts, e.g. [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar/368984#368984) .

You'll have to disable them to be able to see the top of the page again or edit the user script like this https://gist.github.com/vyznev/7c9a7ddc5c057d4c895864e460b4a88d?permalink_comment_id=4115475#gistcomment-4115475

Comment: Thanks - I had forgotten that I had used Stylus to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Stylus user style to make the top bar unsticky again:

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com") {
.ps-fixed.s-topbar { position: absolute !important }
}
```