# Why is the header bar suddenly brighter and with a different layout?

Tags: discussion, support, design, header

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In particular, the profile picture seems a bit jammed in, and the icons have gotten visibly brighter.

What is this change and why did it occur?

Comment: [What is the idea behind the new top header icon color?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377568/idea-behind-new-top-header-icon-color)

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Sorry, couldn't find that for some reason.

Comment: @Ausername Well, since it’s a recent change, it can still be found among the [newest questions](/questions?tab=Newest).