# Please revert the detrimental reduction of notification bubble sizes

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

The site nav bar has bubbles for indicating how many messages you have (red) and how much reputation you have gained (green).

Recently - probably yesterday or today - these bubbles were made much smaller, so that the numbers can all but touch the edge of the bubble. This makes the numbers in the bubbles difficult to read, which is a bug.

So, please fix this by reverting the change.

Note: I've only look at this on SO so far, so if it's a site-specific issue, let me know and I'll refile on Meta.SO.

Comment: It's not site-specific. You're fine to post this here. That said, there's an open feature-request to undo this change (via an option, to be fair): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377577/622284

Comment: Already requested and [meta-tag:status-review]: [Option to remove fuzzy outline and restore clarity to the counts on new top bar](/q/377577/289905).