# Achievements icon color slightly too dark in top bar when earning a new badge

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, accessibility

I just received a new badge on MSE and was surprised to notice the badge notification color is darker than the reputation notification color. I think this is [a recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377749/665544) and the colors used to be the same.

I think the color is slightly too dark against the background, and it also doesn't catch the attention as well as it used to.

[image: screenshot of notification]